# How do i make my existing ubuntu in a bootable installation CD? I tried remastersys but fails with 11.10

Tags: backup, clone, remastersys

I need to install 10 PC which has identical setup and hardware. So i was trying remastersys but its failing. How can i resolve this or use something else to achieve this?

```
Updating the remastersys.log
cat: /home/remastersys/remastersys/tmpusers: No such file or directory
Cleaning up the install icon from the user desktops
Removing the ubiquity frontend as it has been included and is not needed on the normal system
Calculating the installed filesystem size for the installer
Removing remastersys-firstboot from system startup
 Removing any system startup links for /etc/init.d/remastersys-firstboot ...
   /etc/rc0.d/K20remastersys-firstboot
   /etc/rc1.d/K20remastersys-firstboot
   /etc/rc2.d/S20remastersys-firstboot
   /etc/rc3.d/S20remastersys-firstboot
   /etc/rc4.d/S20remastersys-firstboot
   /etc/rc5.d/S20remastersys-firstboot
   /etc/rc6.d/K20remastersys-firstboot
Making disk compatible with Ubuntu Startup Disk Creator.
Creating md5sum.txt for the livecd/dvd
Creating /var/tmp/custom.iso in /home/remastersys/remastersys
The iso was not created. There was a problem. Exiting
```

**Follow up:**

I also had this method work: [**Method 1: CloneZilla way**](https://askubuntu.com/a/788743/507309)

Comment: Have you already tried the other ways described here? https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCDCustomization. I'm asking because I'd recommend this way to create a custom CD.

Comment: It looks like you've added an answer to your question.  Please move your answer to the answers section.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another two possibilities:

[Relinux](http://www.howtoforge.com/creating-your-own-distributable-ubuntu-dvd-relinux) (a fork of Remastersys).

Or, what I do to clone a machine, is copy the entire disk with [CloneZilla](http://www.clonezilla.org/) and clone the disk. Ubuntu is good at automatically reconfiguring when it finds itself on new hardware. There is one change you would have to make in three different files on each machine that you have cloned:

- Change the computer name in `/etc/hostname`, `/etc/hosts` and `/etc/samba/smb.conf` (otherwise you will have conflicts on the network).

Answer (score 1):

**Method 2: ReLinux way**

```
$ sudo cp -R usr /
$ sudo cp -R etc /
$ cat /usr/share/doc/relinux/README
 Relinux

- a script to remaster your Linux distribution easily

For more information, please visit http://relinux.sf.net/


How to configure:
=================
Type this into a Terminal window to generate the configuration file:

  cp /etc/relinux/relinux.conf ./relinux.conf
  sed -i 's:EXCLUDES="\(.*\)":EXCLUDES="\1 '`readlink -f ./relinux.conf`'":g' ./relinux.conf

Then open ./relinux.conf in your favorite text editor, and change the values as you wish.
Some splash images are stored in /etc/relinux/relinux/splash/
When you run the script, make sure that you are in the same directory.

How to use:
===========
Usage is as follows:

  sudo relinux clean [configfile]     -  Cleans the temporary build directory
  sudo relinux fullclean [configfile] -  Fully cleans the temporary build directory (including the ISO file)
  sudo relinux squashfs [configfile]  -  Generates a .squashfs file based on your system
  sudo relinux onlyiso [configfile]   -  Generates a .iso file, using the squashfs file generated by the previous command
  sudo relinux iso [configfile]       -  Runs the last 2 commands

Joel Leclerc, lkjoeldev@gmail.com
$ cp /etc/relinux/relinux.conf ./relinux.conf
$ sed -i 's:EXCLUDES="\(.*\)":EXCLUDES="\1 '`readlink -f ./relinux.conf`'":g' ./relinux.conf
$ vim ./relinux.conf 
edited my username there and saved it
$ sudo relinux fullclean ../relinux.conf
Checking for bash                    [  OK  ]
Checking for sed                     [  OK  ]
Checking for find                    [  OK  ]
Checking for passwd                  [  OK  ]
Checking for rsync                   [  OK  ]
Checking for mount                   [  OK  ]
Checking for eject                   [  OK  ]
Checking for libdebian-installer4    [  OK  ]
Checking for memtest86+              [  OK  ]
Checking for casper                  [  OK  ]
Checking for mksquashfs              [  OK  ]
Checking for unsquashfs              [  OK  ]
Checking for genisoimage             [  OK  ]
Checking for os-prober               [  OK  ]
Checking for ubiquity                [  OK  ]
Checking for user-setup              [  OK  ]
Checking for discover-config         [  OK  ]
Checking for laptop-detect           [  OK  ]
Checking for xterm                   [  OK  ]
Checking for syslinux                [  OK  ]
Checking for util-linux              [  OK  ]
Checking for xresprobe               [  OK  ]
Checking for archdetect              [  OK  ]
Checking for tree                    [  OK  ]
Checking for dialog                  [  OK  ]
Checking for initramfs-tools         [  OK  ]
Checking for coreutils               [  OK  ]
Cleaning...
Done

$ sudo relinux iso ../relinux.conf
Checking for bash                    [  OK  ]
Checking for sed                     [  OK  ]
Checking for find                    [  OK  ]
Checking for passwd                  [  OK  ]
Checking for rsync                   [  OK  ]
Checking for mount                   [  OK  ]
Checking for eject                   [  OK  ]
Checking for libdebian-installer4    [  OK  ]
Checking for memtest86+              [  OK  ]
Checking for casper                  [  OK  ]
Checking for mksquashfs              [  OK  ]
Checking for unsquashfs              [  OK  ]
Checking for genisoimage             [  OK  ]
Checking for os-prober               [  OK  ]
Checking for ubiquity                [  OK  ]
Checking for user-setup              [  OK  ]
Checking for discover-config         [  OK  ]
Checking for laptop-detect           [  OK  ]
Checking for xterm                   [  OK  ]
Checking for syslinux                [  OK  ]
Checking for util-linux              [  OK  ]
Checking for xresprobe               [  OK  ]
Checking for archdetect              [  OK  ]
Checking for tree                    [  OK  ]
Checking for dialog                  [  OK  ]
Checking for initramfs-tools         [  OK  ]
Checking for coreutils               [  OK  ]
########################
## STEP 1 of SquashFS ##
########################
Installing/Removing all packages needed to install/remove
Removing    Popularity Contest   [  OK  ]
Installing  GTK Frontend for Ubiquity    [  OK  ]
########################
## STEP 2 of SquashFS ##
########################
Creating CD tree in /home/relinux
Done
/home/relinux
├── dummysys
│   ├── dev
│   ├── etc
│   ├── media
│   │   └── cdrom
│   ├── mnt
│   ├── proc
│   ├── sys
│   ├── tmp
│   └── var
└── ISOTMP
    ├── casper
    ├── isolinux
    └── preseed

14 directories, 0 files
########################
## STEP 3 of SquashFS ##
########################
Copying /etc and /var to a temporary directory, so that we can work on them
Done. Removing unneeded files, and changing others
Done
########################
## STEP 4 of SquashFS ##
########################
Setting up ISOLINUX
Creating filesystem.manifest and filesystem.manifest-desktop
Setting Casper, Ubiquity, and LSB_RELEASE options
Copying your kernel and initrd to the livecd
########################
## STEP 5 of SquashFS ##
########################
Creating filesystem.squashfs
This will take a while so be patient
Adding stage 1 files/folders that the livecd requires.
Adding stage 2 files/folders that the livecd requires.
This will probably take longer than the first stage.
Calculating the installed filesystem size for the installer
Done
Creating MD5 sum
Done
Finished generating SquashFS file.
##############################
## STEP 1 of ISO Generation ##
##############################
Detecting your tools for ISO generation
Done
##############################
## STEP 2 of ISO Generation ##
##############################
Verifying your SquashFS file
Done. No errors.
##############################
## STEP 3 of ISO Generation ##
##############################
Making disk compatible with Ubuntu Startup Disk Creator.
##############################
## STEP 4 of ISO Generation ##
##############################
Making temporary MD5 Sums for generation of the ISO file
###########################################
## STEP 5 of ISO Generation (final step) ##
###########################################
Creating the ISO file and MD5 sum for it
Creating custom.iso in /home/relinux
Creating custom.iso.md5 in /home/relinux
Done

/home/relinux/custom.iso is generated. It is recommended to run it inside a virtual machine before you release it.

The size of /home/relinux/custom.iso is 1.4G
You will need to burn a DVD/USB/Blu-Ray disk instead of a CD.

It is recommended to run 'sudo relinux clean' (without quotes) once you have burned and tested custom.iso
It will not delete custom.iso or custom.iso.md5
```

Perfectly worked.

Answer (score 0):

**Method 1: CloneZilla way:**

1) I am unhappy that there is nothing exist for this to recover/backup 11.10

2) Anyway i have to do it

3) I did not used the popular Clonezilla because it does not offer me iso

4) I downloaded: http://clonezilla-sysresccd.hellug.gr/download.html

a) created a bootable CD from that ISO

b) booted and followed those steps

http://clonezilla-sysresccd.hellug.gr/restore.html

c) i got a iso file with everyhing on it including boot-loaders

5) then in another system i used my same CD to restore my image

*(posted this answer from question as this was confusing to me that the answer was in the question, probably would be confusing to others)*